# Dishwasher leaks water but doesn't work?

Tags: dishwasher

Our recently replaced  dishwasher doesn't work AT ALL. If I turn it on nothing happens, but I can hear the timer running on it. I have checked power cords and what I could see. We never use our DW so it hasn't been a big deal except for the fact that the bottom is filled with nasty water.

But twice now in the last couple weeks, when we have washed dishes (in the sink) water starts leaking from our DW! It just did it to me a bit ago and my whole kitchen floor was soaked.

Since our landlord doesn't accept maintenance calls and requires a written letter, it will take a while before I hear from him. Is there something I should check myself? 
It is an older style DW, nothing fancy. No cancel or drain buttons to try.

Comment: Can you tell if leaking is from door or underneath?  Can you see a hose about 1-1/2 inches coming from the dish washer area running to the disposal?

Answer (score 1):

The dishwasher should drain into the disposer so it sounds like you have a combination of 2 problems:

1) significant blockage in your sink drain p-trap that is causing water to backup into the dishwasher (path of least resistance). However, it still shouldn't leak normally.

2) the DW drain wasn't done with an air gap or high loop that prevents #1. In other words, the drain hose should run out of the DW, then much higher than where it connects to the disposer before dropping down again to enter the disposer.

That doesn't answer why it is leaking though. Poor drain connection, bad pump, bad seals. If it leaks that bad, it may be a blessing it hasn't worked.